# Two factor or two step requirement for developer accounts - which is it?

Tags: apple-id

Apple will soon require "[two factor authentication](https://developer.apple.com/support/authentication/)" on accounts that access App Store Connect or their developer portal.

I have been trying to figure if they actually mean "two factor or two step" authentication, or they really mean only two-factor.

Background:

- Two-factor = using a trusted Apple device
- Two-step = using SMS

However, although these are the strict definitions, Apple often uses the phrase "two factor" as a shortcut for "two factor or two step".

I wouldn't really be concerned, except they keep sending us warning emails about this change on our Apple developer account which does already have two-step verification enabled.

I'm trying to get their support line to clarify, but maybe someone else knows for sure?

Comment: Apple support has said: Two-Factor Authentication is indeed mandatory for all users in a team including admins, app manager, developer, account holder, and etc. 

There are special regions where Two-Factory Authentication is not available to them; therefore, Two-Step Verification will take place for those regions.

Comment: Not really sure if I believe them, the docs are sufficiently vague and their first answer was also vague.